# Postgres update with an inner join across 2 tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, inner-join, rdbms

I have 3 tables in my local Postgres database:

```
[myschema].[animals]
--------------------
animal_id
animal_attrib_type_id (foreign key to [myschema].[animal_attrib_types])
animal_attrib_value_id (foreign key to [myschema].[animal_attrib_values])

[myschema].[animal_attrib_types]
--------------------------------
animal_attrib_type_id
animal_attrib_type_name

[myschema].[animal_attrib_values]
--------------------------------
animal_attrib_value_id
animal_attrib_value_name
```

At runtime I will know the `animal_id`. I need to run SQL to update the `animal_attribute_value_name` associated with this item, so something like:

```
UPDATE
    animal_attribute_values aav
SET
    aav.animal_attribute_value_name = 'Some new value'
WHERE
    # Somehow join from the provided animal_id???
```

I may have to do some kind of nested `SELECT` or `INNER JOIN` inside the `WHERE` clause, but not sure how to do this. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

Let's say I have an `animal` record with the following values:

```
[myschema].[animals]
--------------------
animal_id = 458
animal_attrib_type_id = 38
animal_attrib_value_id = 23
```

And the corresponding `animal_attrib_value` (with id = 23) has the following values:

```
[myschema].[animal_attrib_values]
--------------------------------
animal_attrib_value_id = 23
animal_attrib_value_name = 'I am some value that needs to be changed.'
```

At runtime, I only have the `animal_id` (458). I need to look up the corresponding `animal_attrib_value` (23) and change its `animal_attrib_value_name` to `'Some new value'`, all inside of a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: What is the meaning of the [] around the identifiers?

Comment: nothing, just there for visual appeal; helps me see "segments" (schemas, tables, fields) that much easier; guess i borrowed it from my MS SQL days

Comment: Your intention is not clear. Do you want to update an "animal", changing one of its attributes to (point to)a new value? Also: actual table definitions would help.

Comment: "some new value " from any table or static one..?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - At runtime I will know the animal whose corresponding animal_attrib_value I want to update. Notice that on the `animals` table I have a foreign key to `animal_attrib_values`. This foreign key should not change, only the corresponding `animal_attrib_value_name`.

Comment: I have edited my question because I realize the `animal_attribute_type` doesn't factor into this at all; I should be able to update the animal's corresponding `animal_attrib_value_name` with just the `animal_id` alone.

Comment: It is clear that you have some (reduced) kind of EntityAttributeValue( EAV) data model, but your intention is still not clear.

Comment: @wildplasser - I have edited my answer with a specific example. Please let me know if its still unclear as to what I'm asking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    animal_attribute_values aav
SET
    animal_attribute_value_name = 'Some new value'
FROM animals aa
WHERE aa.animal_id = 458
AND aa.animal_attrib_value_id = aav.animal_attrib_value_id
  ;
```

Answer (score 4):

are you asking something like this right..?

```
update  animal_attribute_values aav
set  aav.animal_attribute_value_name = 'Some new value'
where aav.animal_attrib_value_id in (
select a.animal_attrib_value_id where a.animal_id=458)
```

try this..

Comment: thanks (+1) - please see the example in my edit. Can you confirm that your code above accomplishes what I'm looking for in my example? Thanks again!